# Any order preserving map of a poset into itself has a fixed point

Tags: relations, order-theory, lattice-orders

In the book of *Algebra* by Hungerford, at pafe 15, it is claimed that
[image]

However, consider $(\mathbb{R}, \leq)$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x+1$. It is a complete partially ordered set with an order preserving map. However, this map do not have any fixed point, so am I missing something in here ?

Comment: What is the least upper bound of $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Your title says (falsely) that an order-preservimg map of **a poset** into itself has a fixed point, but the excercise you quote says (correctly) that an order-preserving map of **a complete lattice** into itself has a fixed point. Why do you do this? Did you think that "poset" and "complete lattice" were synonyms?

Comment: @bof Possibly the OP is confusing complete metric spaces with complete lattices.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yeah, I have missed that property in my counterexample. Thank for pointing out.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown No, I'm not confusing those. I was just trying to create a trivial counterexample.